# Failed to load Power BI workspaces

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-stream-analytics

I have a problem with the stream analytics output configuration. When I create an output to connect to Power BI, I get the message "Failed to load Power BI workspaces". The problem occurs even when logging into the Power BI account through authorization. My Power BI account is in PRO status.

[image]

Comment: Similar issue for this? https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-synapse-analytics/power-bi-linked-service-failed-to-load-workspace/ba-p/1493376

Comment: I created a workspace on powerbi.com but the problem persists.